# PHPMyAdmin. Нету кнопки - Пользователи.Что делать? :D

Tags: phpmyadmin

Нету кнопки - Пользователи.Что делать? :D

версия MySQL : 5.6[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База данных используется с помощью программы Open Server 5.2.2

Comment: Оу...Значит, на курсах меня дезинформировали :D

Comment: А где собственно она должна быть?

Comment: среди функций БД

Comment: среди вкладок БД

Comment: Под root зашел?

Comment: О,точно,спасибо великое :3

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб импортировать БД, сперва нужно создать новую БД. Для этого необходимо в cPanel, в разделе "Базы данных" найти подраздел "Помощник база данных MySQL". Дальше действуй по инструкции https://hostiq.ua/wiki/ukr/migrate-mysql-database/ . Ищи информацию, где нужно перенести БД. Принцип тот же.